# Unicode composition on Xubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, keyboard, unicode

I've just installed Xubuntu, but i noticed that the combination to compose unicode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> isn't working.

Normally an underscored 'u' should appear and i should be able to type the code for the character i want, but this isn't happening.

Oddly enough, it works fine at the login screen when i'm typing my password.

This is a fresh install with very little software installed.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed changing the input method from **XIM** to **None** in
**Language Support**.

Posting here because i haven't been able to find this solution on AskUbuntu.

[image]

Comment: The same fix worked for me. Setting the input method system to IBus also worked. Worth noting that I had to restart the session (log out and then back in) for the changes to take effect.